# Video Editing rendering issue

Tags: rendering, video

I am trying to make a video, I watched several videos to get my settings correct and have made all of my cuts. In the preview, the video is exactly as I want, when I then go to render it, it renders something else, mainly all of the deleted scenes. The render window settings show the same as my preview and sequencer settings so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Hello, can you post a screenshot of your compositing node tree ?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.